# Reverting to previous kernel to avoid booting the new one that breaks my system

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel

I am on 14.04 and just did an update on one of my web servers. I am using the GUI. I ran the updates and it broke my VM.

I am new to Ubuntu and Linux in general so please bear with me.

I was able to get the VM to load by selecting a previous kernel on the boot loader.

My question is, how do I revert back to that kernel so that this VM does not boot into it every time the machine is restarted?

Answer (score 3):

The [grub2 documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/Simple-configuration.html) refers to some useful settings that can be used to set the default boot option.

Edit `/etc/default/grub` (you need root privilege to do this) and change and/or add the following settings:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true
```

and then run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

On the next reboot, select the kernel you want to boot from now on.  The next reboot should boot from that selected kernel.

Answer (score 3):

backup old version

```
sudo cp /etc/default/grub /etc/default/grub.backup
```

edit grub config file

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub

#GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_DEFAULT="Advanced options for Ubuntu>Ubuntu, with Linux 3.16.0-50-generic"
```

Update prior line for the kernel you want  to boot from

save, then

```
sudo update-grub

sudo reboot
```