# Updated Ubuntu after reboot doesn't work properly. Using Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 20.04, kernel, updates

A few notes before I explain the issue:

- Using Ubuntu 20.04 for a couple of months now. I had no issues with updating.
- I'm a novice at using Linux based OS, so pardon my bad terminology.
- I'm using dual boot with Win10, dual boot has worked fine and still is.
- Win10 works perfectly and I haven't noticed any issues regarding it.

I updated from 0-53 to 0-58 then after I restarted the system it doesn't function properly. When I boot into it I noticed several things:

- there is no internet, I tried using the LAN cable but nothing happens
- `sudo` command doesn't work in terminal, just frezees and doesn't prompt for password
- to get into settings it takes a while, also some programs won't even open, like Brave browser

Whilst it was updating, I was working in VIM it just crashed mid-update and told me it terminated Docker, after the update finished I continued working in VIM like everything was normal.

Before I rebooted the system I had installed Dash to Dock which I uninstalled some time ago when it made my dock stuck to the bottom part of the screen. Now I tried to fix that but it just made me have two docks and the expansion crashed, after that I rebooted and found out my system was in a complete disaster.

Also, whilst in Grub menu in Advanced options for Ubuntu there is an older version (5.4.0-53-generic) which works just fine as far as I can notice.

Tried fixing broken packages in recovery mode for the updated version but it doesn't help.

Thanks in advance.

Here's a screenshot of the contents of my `boot/` directory, I thought it might help since I saw somewhere that this issue could be resolved, perhaps, by removing the new version and going back to the old one.

[Contets of `boot/` directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNY0u.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [failed ubuntu 20.04 installation upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1238355/failed-ubuntu-20-04-installation-upgrade)

Comment: @Raffa No, it doesn't. A bit more context, it seems the issues is with the new kernel version (5.4.0-58). Only by into 5.4.0-53 can I do something in the terminal, as that version is completely fine, whilst the newer one (5.4.0-58) seems completely broken.

Comment: See if [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/739002/reverting-to-previous-kernel-to-avoid-booting-the-new-one-that-breaks-my-system0) or **be careful** [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/945403/how-to-downgrade-kernel-after-bad-update-16-04) helps.